# How to Create Traineddata file For Tesseract 4.1.0

Tags: ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract, openalpr, automatic-license-plate-recognition

I want to recognise the characters of NumberPlate.
How to train the tesseract-ocr for respective number plate in ubuntu 16.04. 
Since i don't familiar with training. Please help me to create a 'traineddata' file for recognizing numberplate.

[image: sample Number plate for which i want to detect character]

[image: sample Number plate for which i want to detect character.]

I have 1000 images of number plate.

Please look into it.
Any help would be appreciate.

So I have tried the following commands

```
tesseract [langname].[fontname].[expN].[file-extension] [langname].[fontname].[expN] batch.nochop makebox

tesseract eng.arial.plate3655.png eng.arial.plate3655 batch.nochop makebox
```

But it gives error.

```
Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v4.1.0-rc1-56-g7fbd with Leptonica
Error, cannot read input file eng.arial.plate3655.png: No such file or directory
Error during processing.
```

after that i have tried

```
tesseract plate4.png eng.arial.plate4 batch.nochop makebox
```

it works but in some plates.
    Now in Step 2. I am getting error.

Screenshot is attached.

Plate 4 image for training

[image]

Step 1 and Ste p2 display in terminal

[image]

File Generated after step 1 and step 2

[image]

Content of file generated after step 1 and step 2

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Creating .traineddata for Tesseract 4**

{*Note : After install tesseract open cmd and do the following.}

Step 1: 
    Make box files for images that we want to train

Syntax:

```
tesseract [langname].[fontname].[expN].[file-extension] [langname].[fontname].[expN] batch.nochop makebox
```

Eg:

```
tesseract own.arial.exp0.jpg own.arial.exp0 batch.nochop makebox
```

{*Note:After making box files we have to change or modify wrongly identified characters in box files.}

Step 2:
    Create .tr file (Compounding image file and box file)

Syntax:

```
tesseract [langname].[fontname].[expN].[file-extension] [langname].[fontname].[expN] box.train
```

Eg:
        tesseract own.arial.exp0.jpg own.arial.exp0 box.train

step 3:
    Extract the charset from the box files (Output for this command is unicharset file)

Syntax:

```
unicharset_extractor [langname].[fontname].[expN].box
```

Eg:

```
unicharset_extractor  own.arial.exp0.box
```

step 4:
    Create a font_properties file based on our needs.

Syntax:

```
echo "[fontname] [italic (0 or 1)] [bold (0 or 1)] [monospace (0 or 1)] [serif (0 or 1)] [fraktur (0 or 1)]" > font_properties
```

Eg:

```
echo "arial 0 0 1 0 0" > font_properties
```

Step 5:
    Training the data.

Syntax:

```
mftraining -F font_properties -U unicharset -O [langname].unicharset [langname].[fontname].[expN].tr
```

Eg:

```
mftraining -F font_properties -U unicharset -O own.unicharset own.arial.exp0.tr
```

Step 6:

Syntax:

```
cntraining [langname].[fontname].[expN].tr
```

Eg:

```
cntraining own.arial.exp0.tr
```

{*Note:After step 5 and step 6 four files were created.(shapetable,inttemp,pffmtable,normproto) }

Step 7:
    Rename four files (shapetable,inttemp,pffmtable,normproto) into ([langname].shapetable,[langname].inttemp,[langname].pffmtable,[langname].normproto)

Syntax:

```
rename filename1 filename2
```

Eg:

```
    rename shapetable own.shapetable
    rename inttemp own.inttemp
    rename pffmtable own.pffmtable
    rename normproto own.normproto
```

Step 8:
    Create .traineddata file

Syntax:

```
combine_tessdata [langname].
```

Eg:

```
combine_tessdata own.
```

{ *Note : I will use only one image exp0 for creating traineddata.if you want to train more than one image you can train i.e exp1,exp2..expn }

[Reference](http://pretius.com/how-to-prepare-training-files-for-tesseract-ocr-and-improve-characters-recognition/)

Comment: Please provide an explanation with your answer.

Comment: For creating *.traineddata file you should do the above mentioned steps.after that copy the *.traineddata and paste it on /path/Tesseract-OCR/tessdata.When running tesseract give the command as "tesseract inputimage outputfile -l yourlang". if you create traineddata file as "own.traineddata" , replace "yourlang" with "own".

Comment: For number plate recognition you have to train number plate images as much as possible.Also you can use  --use-words option to recognize probably number plate mostly having words.