# What is font_properties in making traineddata for Tesseract OCR?

Tags: javascript, tesseract

I'm trying to create a traineddata file to train tesseract how to read the images I will feed it but I don't understand what to include in the font_properties step.
I'm following [this](https://pretius.com/how-to-prepare-training-files-for-tesseract-ocr-and-improve-characters-recognition/) example and the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55036633/how-to-create-traineddata-file-for-tesseract-4-1-0) post. Both examples only put 0 and 1 as values for font_properties and my traineddata file is for specific alphanumeric values. Would you tell me more about what to include in step 3 in the second link I sent you. Can it be anything, is it just like a plain description for the font or is it actually important and needs to be accurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Each line of the font_properties file is formatted as follows:
> fontname italic bold fixed serif fraktur where fontname is a string
> naming the font (no spaces allowed!), and italic, bold, fixed, serif
> and fraktur are all simple 0 or 1 flags indicating whether the font
> has the named property.
>
> Example:
>
> timesitalic 1 0 0 1 0

https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/tess3/Training-Tesseract-3.03%E2%80%933.05.html#set_unicharset_properties

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I get it now. 1 is for yes and 0 for no. I was thinking about it different. I understand now that, for instance, if I the font is bold I would give bold a value of 1.