# Tesseract OCR Can't create .traineddata

Tags: cmd, ocr, tesseract, training-data

**The Problem:**

I followed the step by step tutorial provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55036633/how-to-create-traineddata-file-for-tesseract-4-1-0) to train my tesseract ocr for a new font. But on step 5 and 6 not all needed files are created.

**What I did:**

*My image file is: en.va.exp0.tif*

Step 1: *Creating the .box file + correcting wrongly identified characters*

```
tesseract en.va.exp0.jpg en.va.exp0 batch.nochop makebox
```

Step 2: *Creating .tr file*

```
tesseract en.va.exp0.tif en.va.exp0 box.train
```

Step 3: *Extracting the charset from the box files*

```
unicharset_extractor  en.va.exp0.box
```

Step 4: *Create font_properties file*

```
echo "va 0 0 1 0 0" > font_properties
```

Step 5: *Training the data*

```
mftraining -F font_properties -U unicharset -O en.unicharset en.va.exp0.tr
```

Step 6: *Training the data*

```
cntraining en.va.exp0.tr
```

As far as I know step 5 should create 4 files:
shapetable, inttemp, pffmtable, normproto. But only the shapetable file is created. Because of that step 6 also doesn't work (it simply does nothing i think)

**Materials:**

[explorer-screenshot-before.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Sd5V.jpg)

[explorer-screenshot-after.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBxkf.jpg)

[cmd-screenshot.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5Rp6.jpg)

[en.va.exp0.tif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqSRO.png)

**If more explanation or material is needed I'll add it and thanks in advance**

Comment: I'm facing almost the same issue - `mftraining` runs indefinitely and returns nothing. Did you manage to solve it somehow?

Comment: Sadly no, I didn't manage to fix this :( If you manage to solve it pls let me know though

Answer (score 0):

Try running Tesseract 4 instead of Tesseract 5.

Comment: this don't solved the problem. Please any body that support this issue?

Comment: you can follow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55036633/how-to-create-traineddata-file-for-tesseract-4-1-0/77409649#77409649)